# ColdFusion site sometimes uses wrong database

Tags: coldfusion, iis-6, coldfusion-11

I am working on two ColdFusion sites (say "Site A" and "Site B") that are setup on the same server using IIS. Both sites have the same source code, but different URL's and data sources. "Site A" uses database DB1 and "Site B" uses DB2.

The issue is, sometimes I noticed that "Site B" is using DB1 instead of DB2. This issue doesn't appear every time. For example if I hit a page 10 times, about 7 times it uses the correct database and 3 times the wrong database. This issue is not with "Site A", only with "Site B".

I tried many solution like recreating the data sources, dumping the database on each step, but have not found the exact reason. Is any one else facing this issue? Do I need to update ColdFusion?

Comment: *same source code* First guess would be something in the code is pointing to the wrong place.  How are you referencing the datasource in CF code (Application.cfc datasource, multiple cfquery tags, ...)? Do the 2 Application.cfc files have different application names?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes datasource is referencing in CF code (in Application.cfc). Application name is same for both site. May I change the application name?

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing application name solve this issue. Same issue explain in following article: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1845-making-sure-your-coldfusion-applications-are-uniquely-named.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Expanded from comments ....)

First guess would be something in the code is pointing to the wrong place. 
How are you referencing the datasource in CF code (datasource setting in the Application.cfc)? Do the 2 Application.cfc files have *different* application names? They should. Otherwise, both applications will share the same settings. Since the Application.cfc executes at the start of each request, that could produce [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) as multiple threads may read and write the shared datasource setting at the same time.

Example:

1. "John" requests page in **SiteA**. SiteA's Application.cfc executes. The application datasource is set to **DatasourceA**;

   ```
   component {
      this.name = "MyApplication";
      this.datasource = "DatasourceA";
   }
   ```
2. At the same time, "Mike" requests a page in **SiteB**. SiteB's Application.cfc executes. The application datasource is changed to **DatasourceB**

   ```
   component {
      this.name = "MyApplication";
      this.datasource = "DatasourceB";
   }
   ```
3. Then John's request on **SiteA** runs a query. Since the application datasource is now **DatasourceB**, the request queries the wrong database.

The solution is to use different application names in the Application.cfc.